# The objects aren't displayed: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 2 Firestore Query

Tags: java, android

First I do a Query from Firestore to take some data.
I have 2 RecyclerViews.
In the first one, I show data from an SQLite database.
In the second one, I can't show data from a Firestore Query (the objects aren't displayed).

The problem, I think, is because when I want to fill the second RecyclerView the data from Firestore Query haven't arrived yet.

Java class:

```
package com.android.fworkout.fworkout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Recuperar el id del entrenamiento
    //Take training id
    String idEntrenamiento = "";

    //Contexto
    //Context
    Context context;

    //Recuperar ejercicios
    //Take exercises
    static ArrayList<String> listaIdEjercicios = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Ejercicio> listaEjercicios;

    //Base de datos
    //Database
    EjerciciosDBHelper ejercDB;

    //Recuperar jugadores
    //Take players
    static ArrayList<String> listaApodos = new ArrayList<>();
    ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter ljeAdapter;

    //Firestore
    //Firestore
    FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    SharedPreferences sharedPref;

    //XML
    //XML
    EditText etHora, etFecha, etOpinion;
    Button bGuardar;
    RecyclerView rvEjercicios, rvJugadores;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrenamiento_editar_detalle);

        //Coger el contexto de la Activity
        //Take the context of the Activity
        context = this;

        //Recuperar el id del entrenamiento
        //Take training id
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            idEntrenamiento = extras.getString("idEntrenamientoEditar");
        }

        //Limpiar las listas antes de recuperar los datos
        //Clean the lists before recovering the data
        listaIdEjercicios.clear();
        listaApodos.clear();

        //XML
        //XML
        etHora = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etHoraEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);
        etFecha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFechaEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);
        etOpinion = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOpinionEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);
        bGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGuardarEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);
        rvJugadores = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvJugadoresEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);
        rvEjercicios = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvEjerciciosEntrenamientoEditarDetalle);

        //Recuperar id de mi equipo
        //Take id of my team
        sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("PreferenciasFWO", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        rootRef.collection("equipos").document(sharedPref.getString("idEquipo", "")).collection("entrenamientos").document(idEntrenamiento)
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    Log.e("FUNCIONA", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    //Recuperar fecha
                    //Take date
                    etFecha.setText(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("fecha")));
                    //Recuperar hora
                    //Take hour
                    etHora.setText(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("hora")));
                    //Recuperar ejercicios seleccionados
                    //Take selected exercises
                    listaIdEjercicios = (ArrayList<String>) document.getData().get("ejercicios");
                    //Recuperar opinión
                    //Take opinion
                    etOpinion.setText((String) document.getData().get("opinion"));
                    //Recuperar jugadores
                    //Take players
                    listaApodos = (ArrayList<String>) document.getData().get("jugadores");
                    //Log.e("APODOS:", "" + listaApodos.size());

                    //Consultar y mostrar ejercicios
                    //Consult and show exercises
                    ejercDB = new EjerciciosDBHelper(context);
                    listaEjercicios = new ArrayList<>();
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                    rvEjercicios.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    //Añadir ejercicios desde la base de datos local
                    //Add exercises from the local database
                    consultarListaEjercicios();
                    ListaEjerciciosAdapter adapter = new ListaEjerciciosAdapter(listaEjercicios);
                    rvEjercicios.setAdapter(adapter);

                    /*
                     *
                     * NO FUNCIONA       IT DOESN'T WORK
                     *     |||                 |||
                     *     |||                 |||
                     *     |||                 |||
                     *     VVV                 VVV
                     */
                    //Recuperar jugadores
                    //Take players
                    //Cargar datos de mi equipo
                    //Take players of my team
                    Query query = rootRef.collection("equipos").document(sharedPref.getString("idEquipo", "")).collection("jugadores")
                            .orderBy("apodo", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

                    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Jugador> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Jugador>()
                            .setQuery(query, Jugador.class)
                            .build();
                    //Mostrar jugadores
                    //Show players
                    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                    rvJugadores.setLayoutManager(llm);
                    ljeAdapter = new ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter(options);
                    rvJugadores.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    rvJugadores.setAdapter(ljeAdapter);

                } else {
                    //Log.e("ERR56", "768");
                }
            }
        });

        bGuardar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Guardar todo
                //Save all
                //FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                rootRef.collection("equipos").document(sharedPref.getString("idEquipo", "")).collection("entrenamientos").document(idEntrenamiento)
                        .update("fecha", etFecha.getText().toString(),
                                "hora", etHora.getText().toString(),
                                "opinion", etOpinion.getText().toString(),
                                "jugadores", listaApodos,
                                "ejercicios", listaIdEjercicios)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                //Cerrar la Activity
                                //Close the Activity
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                //Avisar del fallo
                                //Warn of the failure
                                Toast.makeText(context, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                //Limpiar las listas después de guardar los datos
                //Clean the lists after saving the data
                listaIdEjercicios.clear();
                listaApodos.clear();
            }
        });
    }


    private void consultarListaEjercicios() {
        SQLiteDatabase sqlLiteDB = ejercDB.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT id AS id, titulo AS titulo, duracion AS duracion, tipo AS tipo FROM ejercicios;";
        Cursor cursor = sqlLiteDB.rawQuery(query, null);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            Ejercicio ejercicio = new Ejercicio();
            ejercicio.id = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(0));
            ejercicio.titulo = cursor.getString(1);
            ejercicio.duracion = cursor.getString(2);
            ejercicio.tipo = cursor.getString(3);

            listaEjercicios.add(ejercicio);
        }
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
package com.android.fworkout.fworkout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;


public class ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Jugador, ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter.JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder> {

    public ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Jugador> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista_jugadores_entrenamiento_adapter, viewGroup, false);
        return new ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter.JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder(v);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Jugador model) {
        String apodoJugador = model.getApodo();
        holder.tvApodo.setText(apodoJugador);
        Log.e("APODOJUGADOR", model.getApodo());

        if (model.getLesionado().equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
            holder.llElementos.setBackgroundColor(0xFF75151E);
        } else {
            if (model.getSancionado().equalsIgnoreCase("si")) {
                holder.llElementos.setBackgroundColor(0xFF0E294B);
            } else {
                holder.llElementos.setBackgroundColor(0xFF57A639);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.size(); i++) {
            if (EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(apodoJugador)) {
                holder.bAnhadir.setText("Eliminar");
                holder.anhadido = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        holder.setOnClickListeners();
    }

    public class JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        Context context;
        TextView tvApodo;
        Button bAnhadir;
        LinearLayout llElementos;

        boolean anhadido = false;

        public JugadorEntrenamientoViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            context = itemView.getContext();
            llElementos = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.llJugadorElementoSeleccionJugadorEntrenamiento);
            tvApodo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvApodoJugadorElementoSeleccionJugadorEntrenamiento);
            bAnhadir = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bAnhadirJugadorElementoSeleccionJugadorEntrenamiento);
        }

        public void setOnClickListeners() {
            bAnhadir.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (anhadido) {
                for (int i = 0; i < EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.size(); i++) {
                    if (EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(tvApodo.getText().toString())) {
                        EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.remove(i);
                        bAnhadir.setText("Añadir");
                        anhadido = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity.listaApodos.add(tvApodo.getText().toString());
                bAnhadir.setText("Eliminar");
                anhadido = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".EntrenamientoEditarDetalleActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/glDatosEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:rowCount="3">

        <!-- Día -->
        <!-- Day -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Fecha" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etFechaEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/Fecha"
            android:inputType="date" />

        <!-- Hora -->
        <!-- Hour -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Hora" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etHoraEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/Hora"
            android:inputType="time" />

        <!-- Opinión -->
        <!-- Opinion -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Opinion" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etOpinionEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/Opinion" />

    </GridLayout>

    <!-- Jugadores y Ejercicios -->
    <!-- Players and Exercises -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bGuardarEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/glDatosEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- Jugadores -->
        <!-- Players -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Jugadores" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvJugadoresEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <!-- Ejercicios -->
        <!-- Exercises -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/Ejercicios" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvEjerciciosEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Guardar -->
    <!-- To save -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGuardarEntrenamientoEditarDetalle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/guardar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

ERROR:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

Comment: `No adapter attached; skipping layout` is not an Error its just an Warning .. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29141729/recyclerview-no-adapter-attached-skipping-layout.

Comment: @ADM sorry, I wrote it bad before.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, the adapter **didn't listen** to the data but if you force to listen to the new data it works:

```
                //Mostrar jugadores
                //Show players
                LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                rvJugadores.setLayoutManager(llm);
                ljeAdapter = new ListaJugadoresEntrenamientoAdapter(options);
                rvJugadores.setHasFixedSize(true);
                rvJugadores.setAdapter(ljeAdapter);
                ljeAdapter.startListening();
```